# Why does "" < {} evaluate to true?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, compare

In JavaScript, why does:

`"" < {}` evaluate to `true` and

`"" < []` evaluate to `false`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `<` coerces its arguments. It prefers to compare numbers, but if the objects don't support a numeric primitive value, it does strings and you end up doing a lexical comparison. `String({})` is `"[object Object]"`, but `String([])` is `""`. `"" < "[object Object]"` is `true`, but `"" < ""` is `false`.

All the gory details are [in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5) (fair warning, the language is turgid to put it mildly).

---

From your comment:

> If it tries numbers first, consider that `Number({})` is `NaN` and `Number([])` is `0`. Comparing `NaN < 0` evaluates to `false`, and so does `0 < NaN`. Why are these results ignored?

I put that poorly originally when I said originally that *"...it tries numbers first..."* (I've updated that). It doesn't. It just *prefers* numbers. Again, full details in soporific detail in the spec (various links from the above), but basically:

- The `<` operation does the abtract [`ToPrimitive`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1) operation on its operands.
- For objects, that invokes the internal [`[[DefaultValue]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8) method with the "hint" "Number".
- `[[DefaultValue]]` (hint = Number) invokes the `valueOf` method of the objects and, if that method returns a primitive, returns it; if the result wasn't a primitive, `[[DefaultValue]]` returns the result of `toString` instead. The `valueOf` method of objects (including arrays) returns the original object unchanged, so the result is `[[DefaultValue]]` returning the result of `toString`.
- The `<` operation sees that the operands are both strings and compares them lexically.

Whereas if the operands were primitive numbers, `ToPrimitive` would return the numbers unchanged, and the `<` would compare them mathematically; if they were `Number` instances (remember JavaScript has both primitive and object versions of numbers, strings, and booleans), `Number#valueOf` would be called by `[[DefaultValue]]`, and `Number#valueOf` returns the primitive number value. And so `<` would compare them mathmatically.

Fun, eh?

Comment: +1 for being quick as a shot! Question: If it tries numbers first, consider that `Number({})` is `NaN` and `Number([])` is `0`. Comparing `NaN < 0` evaluates to `false`, and so does `0 < NaN`. Why are these results ignored?

Comment: @Chiru: Smart question. I put that poorly in the original, I've updated that bit to not be misleading, and added more detail.